# PHP 5.6 to PHP 7 - Sessions / Redirect Not Working Properly on Production Machine

Tags: php, session, php-7

I am attempting to migrate from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.0. I have been doing some testing on my development machine and have not been able to get it to work as expected.

One portion of the application requires users to login. If they are not logged in, and attempt to access a restricted portion of the website, they are redirected to the login page. A session is used to store whether or not a  user is logged in. This works both on my development machine (using PHP 7.0) and the production machine, using PHP 5.6. It does work using PHP 7.0 on the production machine.

It displays the appropriate error message if I enter an incorrect username and password. However, if I enter the correct username and password, the login screen is simply displayed again. There are no errors, and no return URL. I suspect an issue with reading sessions, but I cannot be positive. However, I am not sure why this would be the case - the session.save_path in the php.ini files are the same.

I would really appreciate any guidance on the subject. I am just not sure how to approach this since it works fine on my development machine.

The login UI:

```
  <?php
include_once("config.php");
include(INCLUDEROOT . "includes/header.php");
$return = "teammember/index.php";

?>
<div class='row adminHeader topSection'><div class='col-md-12'><h2>Login</h2></div></div>

<?php 
if(isset($_GET['failed'])) {
    echo "<span class='error'>Invalid login.</span>";
}

if(isset($_GET['returnURL']) && $_GET['returnURL'] != "") {
    $return = formatInput($_GET['returnURL']);
}
?>
<form method='post' action='includes/login.php'>

    <input type='hidden' name='returnURL' value='<?php echo $return; ?>' /> 
    <div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>Username: </label><input type="text" class='form-control' name="user"></div>
    <div class='form-group'><label class='control-label'>Password: </label><input type="password" class='form-control' name="pass"></div>
    <button class='btn btn-primary pull-right' name="login" value="Login">Login</button>
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
</form>

<?php
include(INCLUDEROOT . "includes/footer.php");
?>
```

The login back-end/script

```
    <?php 
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("../config.php");

$dbContext = new DBContext();

session_start();


   $error;
    $username = formatInput($_POST["user"]);
    $pass = formatInput($_POST["pass"]);
    $returnURL = formatInput($_POST['returnURL']);
    if ($dbContext->getUser($username, $pass) != false) {

        $_SESSION["userLevel"] = $dbContext->getUser($username, $pass);

        if ($dbContext->getUser($username, $pass) != 1) {
//             header("Location: " . ROOT . "teammember/index.php");
            header("Location: " . ROOT . $returnURL);
        } else {
//                  header("Location: " . ROOT . "teammember/adminPanel.php");
            header("Location: " . ROOT . $returnURL);
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: " . ROOT . "login.php?failed=true&returnURL={$returnURL}");
    }
```

Code snippet (in header.php) that redirects a user if they have not logged in:

```
    <?php


    if (! isset ( $_SESSION )) {
        session_start ();
    }

    if (empty ( $_SESSION ['userLevel'] )) {
        $returnURL = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        $returnURL = substr($returnURL, 1); /// remove leading slash
        header ( "Location: " . ROOT . "login.php?returnURL=$returnURL" );
    }

    $isAdmin = ((isset ( $_SESSION ['userLevel'] ) && $_SESSION ['userLevel'] == 1) ? true : false);
    ?>
```

Image showing the requests:

[image]

It should not be redirecting from index.php to login.php again (index.php contains the header.php noted above).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you intend to write "have **not** been able to get it to work as expected."?

Comment: Check your error log for `headers already sent` error.

Comment: No errors in the log I am afraid.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION);` show?

Comment: var_dump shows array(1) { ["userLevel"]=> string(1) "2" }

Comment: Then I can't think of any reason why it's rediecting you back to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
if (! isset ( $_SESSION )) {
```

to

```
if (session_id()) {
```

I suspect that `$_SESSION` may be set in PHP 7 to an empty array even when there's no session.

You could also just do an unconditional `session_start()`. If you call `session_start()` when there's already a session in progress, it's ignored.

Comment: Thanks and good point. Unfortunately, it did not resolve the issue, but it is a good observation nonetheless.